# Arranging the grid size and block size

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I have 200 matrices A[i] (whose dimension is 4096*48), and 48 vectors v[j](whose dimension is 48*1). I want to calculate A[i]*v[j], (i=0:199,j=1:47).

I think about how to arrange my grid size and block size from yesterday. But I don't figure out an answer now. Could anyone give me some advice?

Max num of per block is 512. This is my working environment.
[image]

The following is my code. It works right. I have checked. But it is slower than Matlab :(

```
#include<iostream>
#include <mat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "cuda.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

#define kernel_size 48

////////////////////////////////////////////

typedef struct {
    int width;
    int height;
    int stride; 
    float* elements;
} Matrix;



// Forward declaration of the matrix multiplication kernel
__global__ void MatMulKernel(const Matrix, const Matrix, Matrix);
// Matrix multiplication - Host code
// Matrix dimensions are assumed to be multiples of BLOCK_SIZE
void MatMul(const Matrix A, const Matrix B, Matrix C)
{
    // Load A and B to device memory
    Matrix d_A;
    d_A.width = d_A.stride = A.width; d_A.height = A.height;
    size_t size = A.width * A.height * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_A.elements, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_A.elements, A.elements, size,
        cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    Matrix d_B;
    d_B.width = d_B.stride = B.width; d_B.height = B.height;
    size = B.width * B.height * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_B.elements, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_B.elements, B.elements, size,
        cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    // Allocate C in device memory
    Matrix d_C;
    d_C.width = d_C.stride = C.width; d_C.height = C.height;
    size = C.width * C.height * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_C.elements, size);
    // Invoke kernel
    dim3 dimBlock(1,B.height);
    dim3 dimGrid(A.height,  C.width);
    MatMulKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C);
    // Read C from device memory
    cudaMemcpy(C.elements, d_C.elements, size,
        cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    // Free device memory
    cudaFree(d_A.elements);
    cudaFree(d_B.elements);
    cudaFree(d_C.elements);
}
// Matrix multiplication kernel called by MatMul()
__global__ void MatMulKernel(Matrix A, Matrix B, Matrix C)
{
    // Block row and column
    int blockCol = blockIdx.y;
    int blockRow = blockIdx.x;

    float Cvalue = 0;
    // Thread row and column within Csub
    int row = threadIdx.y;
    int col = threadIdx.x;
    // Loop over all the sub-matrices of A and B that are
    // required to compute Csub
    // Multiply each pair of sub-matrices together
    // and accumulate the results


    // Shared memory used to store Asub and Bsub respectively
    __shared__ float As[1][kernel_size];
    __shared__ float Bs[kernel_size][1];
    // Load Asub and Bsub from device memory to shared memory
    // Each thread loads one element of each sub-matrix


    As[0][row] = A.elements[blockRow * A.stride + row+B.height*blockCol];
    Bs[row][0] = B.elements[row];
    // Synchronize to make sure the sub-matrices are loaded
    // before starting the computation
    __syncthreads();
    // Multiply Asub and Bsub together
    for (int e = 0; e < B.height; ++e)
    {
        Cvalue += As[0][e] * Bs[e][0];

    }
    // Synchronize to make sure that the preceding
    // computation is done before loading two new
    // sub-matrices of A and B in the next iteration
    __syncthreads();

    // Write Csub to device memory
    // Each thread writes one element
    C.elements[blockRow * C.stride +blockCol]= Cvalue;
}

//////////////////





float *   gen_matrix(int n /*row*/, int m /*col*/){

    float *A;
    //srand(1023);
    A = (float *) malloc(n*m*sizeof(float));

    for(int row = 0;row < n;row++)
        for(int col = 0;col < m;col++) {
            A[row*m+col] =  rand()%10; 
        }

        /*
        // print matrix elements.
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        cout << " [" << i << "," << j << "] " << A[i*m+j] ;
        cout << endl;
        }
 */
        return  A;
}



int main()
{
    int k=kernel_size;
    int s=2000;
    int m =4096;
    //int m=2;
    //int s=1;
    int n = k*s;
    float *Ae = gen_matrix(m,n);
    float *Be= gen_matrix(k,1);00
    float *Ce=(float *) malloc(m*s*sizeof(float));

    Matrix A ={n,m,n,Ae};
    Matrix B ={1,k,1,Be};
    Matrix C ={s,m,s,Ce};

    const clock_t begin_time = clock();
    MatMul(A,   B,  C);
    std::cout << float( clock () - begin_time ) /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j <7; ++j)
            cout << " [" << i << "," << j << "] " << Ce[i*m+j] ;
        cout << endl;
    }


    //check
    float *Ce2=(float *) malloc(s*m*sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)
        {
            Ce2[i*s+j]=0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)
        {
            for (int ind = 0; ind < k; ind++)
            {
                Ce2[i*s+j]=Ce2[i*s+j]+Ae[j*k+ind+i*k*s]*Be[ind];
            //  printf("%f---****%f\n",Ae[j*k+ind+i*k*s],Be[ind]);
            }
            if (Ce2[i*s+j]!= Ce[i*s+j])
            {
                printf("%f----%f\n",Ce2[i*s+j],Ce[i*s+j]);
            }

        }

    }





    free(Ae);
    free(Be);
    free(Ce);
}
```

Comment: Forget about your Matrix structure, and think how you can arrange your data in single dimensional arrays. Once you do that, grid and block sizes seem like almost arbitrary in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a matrix-matrix multiplication problem.  If you want things to run fast, you should not be writing your own matrix-matrix multiply code.  Use CUBLAS Sgemm.

Conceptually, if you arrange your `A` matrices like this:

```
[A0]
[A1]
[A2]
...
[A199]
```

then you will have a new matrix `AA` that is (4096*200) rows x 48 columns.

Arrange your 48 `V` vectors (48x1) in a 48x48 matrix (`VV`):

```
[V0][V1][V2]...[V47]
```

(each `V` vector is a *column* of the new matrix `VV`)

You now have a single matrix multiplication problem (`AA`*`VV`) that is (4096*200)x48 multiplied by 48x48 which yields a (4096*200) x 48 result.    This result has one column vector of length 4096*200 that contains 200 results of the individual matrix-vector multiplications you were trying to do.  The 200 results per column * 48 columns combine to give you all of the results that your original problem would create.  The first column would contain the results of `[V0]` multiplied by each of the 200 `A` matrices, the second column would contain the results of  `[V1]` multiplied by each of the 200 `A` matrices, etc.

Once you have arranged your data like this, using CUBLAS [Sgemm](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemm) should be the quickest possible approach on the GPU.  Note that CUBLAS expects the underlying storage to be column-major, so if you are rearranging your data, you will probably want to keep this in mind.  There is a [CUDA sample code for CUBLAS matrix multiplication](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#matrix-multiplication--cublas-).

In your code it appears you actually have 2000 `A` matrices, but your question refers to 200.  I have used 200 for example in my answer, but the concept would be the same with 2000 `A` matrices.